# Unable to upload a image into Firebase Storage

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-storage

I was trying to upload a image from camera. I managed to get the image from the camera but when after user picks it, it doesn't show up in the Firebase Storage. Can you help me to find what's wrong

```
var _instance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
FirebaseAuth auth_ = FirebaseAuth.instance;
File? image;
String? downloadLink;
Future pickImage() async {
  var fileToUpload =
      await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  if (image == null) return;
  setState(() {
    image = File(fileToUpload!.path);
  });

  Reference referenceWay = FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref()
      .child('profilePics')
      .child(auth_.currentUser!.uid)
      .child("profilPic.png");

  UploadTask uploadTask = referenceWay.putFile(image!);
  TaskSnapshot downloadURL = (await uploadTask);
  String url = await downloadURL.ref.getDownloadURL();
}
```

Comment: Specify what error you are facing

Comment: There isn't any error. It doesn't show up in Firebase Storage.

Answer (score 0):

Required dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  firebase_storage: ^3.0.8
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.6
  image_picker:
```

[Checkthis:](https://rrtutors.com/tutorials/imagepicker-flutter)

```
final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future pickImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      _imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
    });
  }


File _imageFile;


  Future uploadImageToFirebase(BuildContext context) async {
    String fileName = basename(_imageFile.path);
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('uploads/$fileName');
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_imageFile);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(
          (value) => print("Done: $value"),
        );
  }
```

for iOS:
Add permissions in iOS Info.list

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need to access your camera to capture a photo add and update profile picture.</string>

<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need to access your photo library to select a photo add and update profile picture</string>
```

Sample Code [Example](https://rrtutors.com/tutorials/uploading-image-to-firebase-storage-in-flutter).

Comment: Would old versions of analiytics, storage etc. can create any problem while working with Cloud Firestore?

Comment: Hi, I tried to use this code but I got a `_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)` error in `String fileName = (_imageFile!.path);` line. I'm using versions   firebase_core: ^1.10.2,  firebase_storage: ^10.2.4,
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+4,
  firebase_analytics: ^9.0.4

Comment: Hi, Can you check if this [link](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/5356) helps you with your error?